# JDBCJobStore in Quartz API

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz for an application and It is working fine without the quartz.properties file.
When I include the quartz.properties to use the JDBCJobStore is gives the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Unable to instantiate JobFactory class: org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory cannot be cast to org.quartz.spi.JobFactory [See nested exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory cannot be cast to org.quartz.spi.JobFactory]
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate(StdSchedulerFactory.java:785)    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate(StdSchedulerFactory.java:785)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.getScheduler(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1502)
```

Scheduling Class

```
public class CronTriggerExample {
        public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
        {
            JobKey jobKeyA = new JobKey("jobA", "group1");
            JobDetail jobA = JobBuilder.newJob(JobB.class)
            .withIdentity(jobKeyA).storeDurably(true).build();
             Trigger trigger1 = TriggerBuilder
            .newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("dummyTriggerName1", "group1")
            .withSchedule(
            CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/5 * * * * ?"))
            .build();
            SchedulerFactory schdFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
                Scheduler schd = schdFact.getScheduler();
                schd.start();
            schd.scheduleJob(jobA, trigger1);


        }
    }
```

quartz.properties

```
# Main Quartz configuration
org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck = true
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = MyQuartzScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.jobFactory.class = org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 5
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=false
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDS 
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quartz
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user=root
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password=root
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.maxConnections = 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the following line of code to the properties file

```
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.MSSQLDelegate
```

and removed

```
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=false
```

Its working fine now.